# How to trace root director denoted by / or $ sign?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

```
set -e

debug=0

angleFullFile="$1/$2/$3/$4/angle.2"
calcAngleFolder="/home/sadeed/EPA/MIE_RHESA_EPA/EPA_Pre_Pos_Scritps/calcAngles"
rm -rf $calcAngleFolder
mkdir $calcAngleFolder

echo -e "Doing filter for - $angleFullFile"

while read i
do

    angleName=$(echo $i | tr -d '\r')
    resultFile="$calcAngleFolder/$angleName.angle"
    touch $resultFile
    totalDuplicate=0    

    while read angle
    do
        
        if [[ $angle =~ ^$angleName.+ ]]
        then
            
            duplicate=0

            while read resultAngle
            do
                
                if [[ $angle =~ ^$resultAngle$ ]]
                then

                    duplicate=1
                    ((totalDuplicate++))

                    if [ $debug -eq 1 ]
                    then

                        echo "Duplicate Record Found" 
                        echo "$angle"
                        echo "$resultAngle"

                    fi  

                fi

            done < $resultFile

            if [ $duplicate -eq 0 ]
            then
                
                echo -e "$angle" >> $resultFile

            fi

        fi
    
    done < $angleFullFile

    echo -e "Total duplicate records for angle ( $angleName ) : $totalDuplicate"

    count=0
    numLine=$(wc -l < $resultFile)
    sed -i "1i$numLine" $resultFile

    while read iangle
    do
        
        newStr=${iangle/$angleName/$count}
        output="$(echo $newStr | sed -e "s/ \+/\t/g")"
        sed -i "s/$iangle/$output/g" $resultFile
        count=$((++count))
        
    done < $resultFile

done < $1/$2/$3/$4/cthel.input

cp -r $calcAngleFolder $1/$2/$3/$4
```

When I want the run the above file using filter.bak, I see the following error:

```
./filter.bak: line 1: : command not found
Doing filter for - //////angle.2
./filter.bak: line 78: ////cthel.input: No such file or directory
```

I wonder, i want to names of the of folders denoted by $ or /. Or please assist me figure out where the problem is resulting in the error. and How  to see the names of the directory files denoted by / or $, so that i may be able to declare the path containing cthel.input folder.

I wonder , the problem might lie in declaration of the path file.

```
angleFullFile="$1/$2/$3/$4/angle.2"
calcAngleFolder="/home/sadeed/EPA/MIE_RHESA_EPA/EPA_Pre_Pos_Scritps/calcAngles"
```

I have tried like

```
angleFullFile="$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6 angle.2"
```

but not working/or running.

Comment: Your formatting is messed up. To format a block of text as code, precede and follow it with a line consisting of three backticks.

Comment: yes, hopefully formatted.

Comment: No, the formatting is still messed up.

Comment: Why passing the path components separately as `$1,$2,,,`? Use only 1 arg like `file=$1/angle.2`

Comment: tried running, ./filter.bak after using $1/angle.2 , still the same error.

Comment: where do you think `$1`, `$2`, etc, are defined?

Comment: the author of this code did not define the location for $1,$2, - the location may be as per the location of the directories in his/her pc.

Comment: The first error message says that at line 1 of your script there is a colon (`:`) that your default shell (the one that tries to interpret this script) does not understand. There is no colon in line 1. So, you probably have 2 issues: 1) the script you show us is not the script you are trying to run. Please edit your question and show the **exact** script. 2) your default shell is not bash or zsh because these shells do understand the colon command. Either add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to your script or rewrite it using the syntax of your default shell.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet not colon, something unprintable (or that got lost during transcription). Probably BOM: consider output of `LANG=C.UTF-8 bash -c $'\xef\xbb\xbf'`

Comment: @jhnc You're probably right. Anyway, this must be fixed.